# Tomcat - Listen on two ports for testing purposes

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium, war

I'm doing tests for our application in Java in Selenium framework (rewriting html code to java) and I was wondering if I can listen on two different ports while testing? Deploy war with the full application so I can study the html code and another war for testing. I don't know if you could fully understand what I need to get running here...

Lets say on port 8080 the webapp will be going continuosly full day, on port 8090 the webapp will be running many tests a day. It's like that because I would test a lot features which include adding a post, editing some thing. After another deploy, the webapp would be default (without any myself added data).

Thanks in advance, hope someone can help me with this. I'm not so familiar with Tomcat...

EDIT: Oh, our application runs on Maven

Comment: I don't think you can have two ports.  I don't see why you'd want to.

Comment: Because when the test finishes, I can no longer use the webapp, thats why

Comment: Wut?  This makes no sense at all.

Comment: Why don't you just run two separate tomcats on one machine? I think you're lacking basic understanding of how tomcat works.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many listening ports as you like, *but* you can't restrict them to specific webapps. What you're attempting isn't possible.

You need to run another Tomcat for your testing. You wouldn't want to mix production and dvelopment code in the same Tomcat anyway, it's very poor practice. You need an entirely separate testing environment.

Back in the day, companies used to buy two mainframes: one for production and one for development.

> Our application runs on Maven.

No it doesn't. It runs on Tomcat. Maven is a development tool.